# Cannot override frozen service "twig.app_variable" - Dynamic path to asset function

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, twig, silex

I understand the error I get but can't figure why...

So here is my problem and why I got this error :

1/ I have a php variable `$wdep` that give my the path where I need to find my `/web` file (css, js, lib and img) :

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "127.0.0.1"){
    $wdep = "../../_wdep/v2/mywebsite/";
} else {
    $wdep = "https://wdep ... /v2/mywebsite/"; // I cut some info but the link is valid
}
```

2/ Now, when I registered my `Twig Provider` according to the Twig documentation, I can't use my css, js, etc. :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views',
));
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\AssetServiceProvider(), array(
    'assets.version' => 'v1',
));
```

This works, but in my template but when use the `asset()` function it doesn't work : it's normal because I need to add my `$wdep` path to get it, so this

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/lib/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<img src="{{ asset('/img/logo/logo.png') }}" alt="Logo">
```

don't work.

3/ According to the documentation about the `asset()` function ([here](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/providers/asset.html)), I tried to do those

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\AssetServiceProvider(), array(
    'assets.version' => 'v1',
    'assets.base_urls' => $wdep
));
```

OR

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\AssetServiceProvider(), array(
    'assets.version' => 'v1',
    'assets.named_packages' => array(
        'css' => array('base_urls' => array($wdep)),
        'img' => array('base_urls' => array($wdep)),
        'js'  => array('base_urls' => array($wdep)),
        'lib' => array('base_urls' => array($wdep)),
    ),
));
```

And get my `Cannot override frozen service "twig.app_variable"` error...

**Maybe I am missing something, but do you you know why and how I can add my `$wdep` to my `asset()` function to make it works please?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem just with this line I added after I registered `TwigServiceProvider()` and `AssetServiceProvider()`:

```
$app['assets.base_path'] = $wdep;
```

I used some `var_dump($app)` to find it but I'd like to understand why I can't do it when I registered my `AssetServiceProvider()` ?